# Golang - Returned JSON top level field is variable. How to use in struct

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a JSON response from an API that looks like this:

```
{
    "1091500": {
      "data": {
        "price_overview": {
          "final_formatted": "$59.99"
        }
      } 
    }
}
```

The struct I have works fine when I unmarshal and access the price value I need.
`price.AppID.Data.PriceOverview.FinalFormatted`

struct here:

```
type SteamApp struct {
    AppID struct {
        Data struct {
            PriceOverview struct {
                FinalFormatted string `json:"final_formatted"`
            } `json:"price_overview"`
        } `json:"data"`
    } `json:"1091500"`
}
```

What I'm trying to work through is the top level key, the "1091500." This is a value generated by a separate function and was in fact the search term needed to grab the data above. That being said, it's dynamic and discovered by a separate API call at runtime. Because you need the JSON tag in the struct, I'm struggling to come up with an approach to generalize it.

The best approach so far has been to find a different API that returns the data differently, but I haven't found that yet. I also thought about finding a way to "skip" the initial section because I have the correct data, it's simply the "reading" of it that's the issue. Thank you in advance, I hope I explained myself well enough.

Comment: `SteamApp` is a `map[string]Data`

Comment: @zerkms thanks so much for the hint! I was able to pull out the values I needed with your help. I'm not sure my implementation is idiomatic, but it did achieve the end result I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unmarshal in two steps. First into a map, then into the struct type. You can do this automatically by implementing [json.Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var j = []byte(`{
    "1091500": {
      "data": {
        "price_overview": {
          "final_formatted": "$59.99"
        }
      }
    }
}`)

func main() {
    var t T
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, &t)

    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", t)
}

type T struct {
    AppID         string `json:"-"`
    PriceOverview struct {
        FileFormatted string `json:"final_formatted"`
    } `json:"price_overview"`
}

func (t *T) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var m map[string]struct {
        Data json.RawMessage
    }

    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    type T_ T // prevent recursion
    var t_ T_

    for appID, x := range m {
        err := json.Unmarshal(x.Data, &t_)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        *t = T(t_)
        t.AppID = appID

        break
    }

    return nil
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://go.dev/play/p/NMffrAWEBQy

I am assuming the data property is just noise and made it transparent. If I'm mistaken then use a map[string]json.RawMessage and add the Data field to type T.

If you want to automatically marshal into the same format too implement [json.Marshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshaler) as well:

```
func (t T) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type T_ T // prevent recursion

    m := map[string]struct {
        Data T_ `json:"data"`
    }{
        t.AppID: {Data: T_(t)},
    }

    return json.Marshal(m)
}
```

Comment: hi @Peter thanks so much this is exactly what I needed! without even realizing it i was working under the assumption that i was stuck with whatever unmarshal gives me.